# Select by slugged string/friendly URL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, slug

### The goal

Select data from database using `Name-Of-Product` instead of its id.

### The problem

My application allows the user to compare product prices. To make some comparison I need to access `myapp.com/Product/Compare?Id=1`. I'm upgrading my application and now I want to access `myapp.com/Product/Xbox-360` to make the comparison.

How can I select the *sluggified* word from the database instead of its id? Do I have to *unsluggify* the string?

Can someone enlighten me?

### What I've already tried

I even do not know how to start. In other words, I didn't try nothing. *Oh... Actually, if necessary, I already created a method that can sluggify some string, but I don't think it is  necessary to post here.*

### SQL Spotlight

My query to produce the list of products to compare is simple:

```
Select product.Name,
       marketProduct.Price
From app_products As product
Join app_marketProducts As marketProduct
Where product.Id = 1
```

Comment: Where product.SluggifiedName = "Xbox-360"?

Comment: Hmmmm... Are you telling me that I need a database's column to store the sluggified name?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge, He is.  Have a `SluggifiedName` column which contains the result of... "Sluggification" (ugh), and search using that.

Comment: How do you create the sluggified name in the first place?

Comment: @D.R. I'm using a method (do you want to see it?)

Comment: No, if you cannot implement a method^(-1) to get the ID from the sluggified name (e.g., some sluggified names look like "ID-Name"), you have to save it in the database as well.

Comment: @D.R. Got it. Then I ask: isn't it a bad practice store this information on database, right?

Comment: Seems like a good idea to store this info.  Why would you think it was bad practice?  It's an attribute of the product.

Comment: I guess the best practice is to store the ID within the "slug" as well, see e.g. SO links.

Comment: @D.R. Seems that the ID isn't within the slugged string. Seems they are in separated columns.

Comment: They are, however, that's good enough to query it, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I do not know. Seems to me something like "redundancy". Do you use or approves this approach?

Comment: @D.R. Okay! You convinced me! Want to turn your comment into an answer for me to accept it?

Comment: Done, hope you like the answer, if you miss anything just tell me, I'll go and edit it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have two choices:

- You can store the *slug* in a new column within your database.
- You can add the primary key (the ID) to your URL in some way:

  a) Directly to the slug (e.g. /42-My-Slug)

  b) To another section of the URL (e.g. /42/My-Slug). This seems to be the best practice, e.g. StackOverflow uses it.